# Polymorphing into Giant Porcupine, do you get quills?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, polymorph

Using wild shape or [beast shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/beast-shape), when you choose a [Giant Porcupine](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary3/porcupine.html#porcupine-giant) do you get the quills ability? Its not listed within the beast shape spell, which as a specific spell over rules the more [general polymorph rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation).

> While under the effects of a polymorph spell, you lose all extraordinary and supernatural abilities that depend on your original form (such as keen senses, scent, and darkvision), as well as any natural attacks and movement types possessed by your original form. You also lose any class features that depend upon form, but those that allow you to add features (such as sorcerers that can grow claws) still function. While most of these should be obvious, the GM is the final arbiter of what abilities depend on form and are lost when a new form is assumed. Your new form might restore a number of these abilities if they are possessed by the new form.

So the general rules seem to indicate that you get abilities and likely leaves it upto the spell, but a giant porcupine really should have quills.

Comment: Finally! A porcupine that can be hugged! Magic *is* awesome! `;-)`

Comment: @HeyICanChan Noooo, my magic isnt suppose to be huggable!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By RAW, you do not appear to gain Quills from Beast shape, or from Wildshape (which functions like Beast shape anyway). The text you quoted is listing what you lose, but not really what you gain. The part about what you gain says -

> In addition, each polymorph spell can grant you a number of other benefits, including movement types, resistances, and senses.
>   ...
>   In addition to these benefits, you gain any of the natural attacks of the base creature, including proficiency in those attacks.

And the various Beast Shape variations list a number of specific abilities you can get, none of which generically include Defensive Abilities, or mention Quills (Although, I do see 'spikes' mentioned in IV).

Comment: Yeah, the only exception is that the GM may let you regain some abilities (that are extraordinary and depend on form) if they feel nice.